# Pass through some html

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I use jquery to fill a asp:label

Jquery code:

`$("#more15").text(<p> <b>Hello WOrld!</b> </p>);`

Asp .net code:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="more15" Text="" Font-Size="Small" Font-Italic="False"></asp:Label>
```

When I view the page it is shown like this:

```
<p> <b>Hello WOrld!</b> </p>
```

instead of:

**Hello WOrld!**

how could I fix this problem?

Thanks
/Mikael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```
$("#more15").html("<p> <b>Hello WOrld!</b> </p>");
```

Comment: +1 - Needs a `#` in there to be completely correct, may want to update it for others :)

Comment: @Nick Craver good catch, updated.. guess we should take into consideration the version of asp.net in use also.. it might need to resolve the rendered id as well but I will leave that to the op/viewer.